# jquery draggable: draggable's handle option on the outer border of a box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

How can I configure jquery draggable's `handle` option to the outer layer but not the inner layer of a box?

For instance, I want to drag this popup box below, when only the cursor is clicked and dragged on the **black border** of this popup, but not the content area.

Is it possible?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bCed/)

Currently the box is dragged either you have your cursor in content area or the black border.

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Attach the jquery.ui draggable.
    $('.ps-popup-outer').draggable({ 
        cursor: "move",
        handle: ".ps-popup-outer"
    });

});
```

html,

```
<div class="ps-popup-outer" style="width:400px;">
    <div class="ps-popup-inner" style="height:400px;">
        <div class="box-close"><input type="button" value="Close" class="button-close"/></div>
        <div class="box-content">inner content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or maybe there are better solutions you could suggest?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to use draggable's [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) option, which will prevent dragging on particular elements.

```
 $('.ps-popup-outer').draggable({ 
    cursor: "move",
    handle: ".ps-popup-outer",
    cancel: ".ps-popup-inner"
 });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/4bCed/1/

Hope this helps!